# Quisiera llamar datos con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, entity-framework

Buenas tarde gente quisiera traer datos de una tabla dependiendo un campo

```
int matricula = Convert.ToInt32(txtMatricula.Text);
var list = db.Legajos.Where(l => l.matricula == matricula).Select(l => l.caja);
txtCaja.Text = list.ToString();
```

No estoy pudiendo traer el valor de caja

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir que no estas pudiendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te estoy leyendo bien la mente, creo que esto es lo que estás buscando:

```
int matricula = Convert.ToInt32(txtMatricula.Text);
var caja = db.Legajos
             .Where(l => l.matricula == matricula)
             .Select(l => l.caja)
             .FirstOrDefault() // Podrías usar SingleOrDefault
             .ValorDeLaPropiedadQueTieneLaClaseCaja;
txtCaja.Text = caja.ToString();
```

Lecturas sugerida:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netcore-3.1
- https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1